# How to make rpm auto install dependencies

Tags: linux, installation, package, rpm, yum

I have built two RPM packages

- `proj1-1.0-1.x86_64.rpm`
- `libtest1-1.0-1.x86_64.rpm`

`proj1` depends on the file `libtest1.so` being present and it is reflected correctly in the RPM packages as seen here:

```
user@my-pc:~$ rpm -qp --requires proj1-1.0-1.x86_64.rpm
libtest1.so()(64bit)

user@my-pc:~$ rpm -qp --provides libtest1-1.0-1.x86_64.rpm
libtest1.so()(64bit)
```

The installation of `proj1` fails due to a missing dependency.

```
user@my-pc:~$ rpm -ivh proj1-1.0-1.x86_64.rpm
error: Failed dependencies:
libtest1.so()(64bit) is needed by proj1-1.0-1.x86_64.rpm
```

How do I ensure that `libtest1-1.0-1.x86_64.rpm` is installed automatically during
the installation of `proj1-1.0-1.x86_64.rpm`?

I did try the `--aid` option with `rpm -i` as described [here](http://www.redhat.com/advice/tips/rhce/rpm.html) but it didn't work for me.

Is there any other way?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 118, accepted):

Create a (local) repository and use `yum` to have it resolve the dependencies for you.

The CentOS wiki has a nice page providing a how-to on this. [CentOS wiki HowTos/CreateLocalRepos](http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/CreateLocalRepos).

---

Summarized and further minimized (not ideal, but quickest):

1. Create a directory for you local repository, e.g. `/home/user/repo`.
2. Move the RPMs into that directory.
3. Fix some ownership and filesystem permissions:

   ```
   # chown -R root.root /home/user/repo
   ```
4. Install the `createrepo` package if not installed yet, and run

   ```
   # createrepo /home/user/repo
   # chmod -R o-w+r /home/user/repo
   ```
5. Create a repository configuration file, e.g. `/etc/yum.repos.d/myrepo.repo` containing

   ```
   [local]
   name=My Awesome Repo
   baseurl=file:///home/user/repo
   enabled=1
   gpgcheck=0
   ```
6. Install your package using

   ```
   # yum install packagename
   ```

Comment: The link you provided solved my case with just this one line: `yum --nogpgcheck localinstall packagename.arch.rpm`.

Comment: @Matthew Cool, that would eliminate the whole local repository steps. Post that as an answer I'd say.

Comment: This doesn't work very well if you're trying to script RPM to automate the install of YUM on AIX like me ;-)

Comment: @Max13, that's `yum localinstall` and it is the same as [the answer already posted here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16406806/1254292), with the already discussed downsides for situations where dependencies are *not* in yum repos (see the *this method will not work unless [...]* part).

Comment: Figured this one as well if no internet connection is there `sudo yum --disablerepo=* --enablerepo=local install packagename.arch.rpm` to make sure `yum` does not look into other repositories.

Answer (score 229):

The link @gertvdijk provided shows a quick way to achieve the desired results without configuring a local repository:

```
$ yum --nogpgcheck localinstall packagename.arch.rpm
```

Just change `packagename.arch.rpm` to the RPM filename you want to install.

**Edit** Just a clarification, this will automatically install all dependencies that are already available via system YUM repositories.

If you have dependencies satisfied by other RPMs that are not in the system's repositories, then this method will not work unless each RPM is also specified along with `packagename.arch.rpm` on the command line.

Comment: No, this will not work unless `libtest1-1.0-1.x86_64.rpm` is in a repository elsewhere, or both packages are specified on the command line like "`rpm -i`" would require. I just verified this on `yum` 3.4.3 (Fedora 18). Transcript [here](http://pastebin.com/HpjRtqFh) showing that it goes to the `updates` repo for the dependencies, even when the files are right there.

Comment: @AaronD.Marasco maybe you are correct about the specific case described in the question, but this one-liner is much easier for anyone winding up here like I did, and is a fully valid answer for the question in the title, "How to make rpm auto install dependencies".

Comment: No, it isn't "auto installing" the dependencies - you are specifying them on the command line, the same way you would with "`rpm -i`", so using `yum` gives you no added benefit.

Comment: @AaronD.Marasco I just did this a couple days ago installing Nixnote. Nixnote had dependencies that were not installed so I could not install it with rpm -i. I used the command above and yum automatically installed the dependencies without me having to specify them one by one. So yes, it does automatically install the dependencies.

Comment: Please re-read what I wrote. Any dependencies were downloaded from a repository, even if they were locally available in the directory with the RPM you installed.

Comment: @AaronD.Marasco I'm not debating that the other posted solution is better for the specific example OP was asking about. My answer, however, is correct for answering the question in the title and is *much* faster than configuring a local repo, and will help others who wind up here like I did who want a fast way to get yum to automatically install the dependencies that an rpm requires. That is the purpose of stack overflow, to help the community searching for answers and not just helping the OP.

Comment: @Aaron: I think it's possible that it works as you describe on some systems and as Matthew describes on others.  I have one system where I *swear* it did resolve dependencies out of the local filesystem (as no other repos were configured...) but another where it keeps telling me about missing dependencies, which are *right there* in the pwd.

Answer (score 39):

For dnf users just use `dnf install *.rpm`, `localinstall` is no longer needed.

Comment: Came here to say exactly this

Comment: thanks, I was struggling to install `mysql-workbench` with `rpm -ivh`. eventually ended up with this post. DNF did the trick.

Comment: Works on Fedora 38

Answer (score 30):

For me worked just with

```
# yum install ffmpeg-2.6.4-1.fc22.x86_64.rpm
```

And automatically asked authorization to dowload the depedencies.
Below the example, i am using fedora 22

```
[root@localhost lukas]# yum install ffmpeg-2.6.4-1.fc22.x86_64.rpm
Yum command has been deprecated, redirecting to '/usr/bin/dnf install  ffmpeg-2.6.4-1.fc22.x86_64.rpm'.
See 'man dnf' and 'man yum2dnf' for more information.
To transfer transaction metadata from yum to DNF, run:
'dnf install python-dnf-plugins-extras-migrate && dnf-2 migrate'

Last metadata expiration check performed 0:28:24 ago on Fri Sep 25 12:43:44 2015.
Dependencies resolved.
====================================================================================================================
 Package               Arch           Version                                  Repository                      Size
====================================================================================================================
Installing:
 SDL                   x86_64         1.2.15-17.fc22                           fedora                         214 k
 ffmpeg                x86_64         2.6.4-1.fc22                             @commandline                   1.5 M
 ffmpeg-libs           x86_64         2.6.4-1.fc22                             rpmfusion-free-updates         5.0 M
 fribidi               x86_64         0.19.6-3.fc22                            fedora                          69 k
 lame-libs             x86_64         3.99.5-5.fc22                            rpmfusion-free                 345 k
 libass                x86_64         0.12.1-1.fc22                            updates                         85 k
 libavdevice           x86_64         2.6.4-1.fc22                             rpmfusion-free-updates          75 k
 libdc1394             x86_64         2.2.2-3.fc22                             fedora                         124 k
 libva                 x86_64         1.5.1-1.fc22                             fedora                          79 k
 openal-soft           x86_64         1.16.0-5.fc22                            fedora                         292 k
 opencv-core           x86_64         2.4.11-5.fc22                            updates                        1.9 M
 openjpeg-libs         x86_64         1.5.1-14.fc22                            fedora                          89 k
 schroedinger          x86_64         1.0.11-7.fc22                            fedora                         315 k
 soxr                  x86_64         0.1.2-1.fc22                             updates                         83 k
 x264-libs             x86_64         0.142-12.20141221git6a301b6.fc22         rpmfusion-free                 587 k
 x265-libs             x86_64         1.6-1.fc22                               rpmfusion-free                 486 k
 xvidcore              x86_64         1.3.2-6.fc22                             rpmfusion-free                 264 k

Transaction Summary
====================================================================================================================
Install  17 Packages

Total size: 11 M
Total download size: 9.9 M
Installed size: 35 M
Is this ok [y/N]: y
```

Comment: easiest way i think

Comment: Not a direct rpm solution, but I like this best.

Comment: Not a RPM solution but is the most easiest way to install dependencies with only one command. This worked flawless for me

Answer (score 11):

I found a simpler solution. If you have all the RPMs in the same directory, all you need to do is,

```
$ sudo rpm -i *.rpm
```

`rpm` seems to figure out the correct order to install these and installs the RPMs.

Comment: That still not handle the case if the dependencies are not in current directory.

Answer (score 5):

Matthew's answer awoke many emotions, because of the fact that it still lacks a minor detail.
The general command would be:

```
# yum --nogpgcheck localinstall <package1_file_name> ... <packageN_file_name>
```

The `package_file_name` above can include local absolute or relative path, or be a URL (possibly even an URI).

Yum would search for dependencies among all package files given on the command line AND IF IT FAILS to find the dependencies there, it will also use any configured and enabled yum repositories.

Neither the current working directory, nor the paths of any of `package_file_name` will be searched, except when any of these directories has been previously configured as an enabled `yum` repository.

So in the OP's case the `yum` command:

```
# cd <path with pkg files>; yum --nogpgcheck localinstall ./proj1-1.0-1.x86_64.rpm ./libtest1-1.0-1.x86_64.rpm
```

would do, as would do the `rpm`:

```
# cd <path with pkg files>; rpm -i proj1-1.0-1.x86_64.rpm libtest1-1.0-1.x86_64.rpm
```

The differencve between these `yum` and `rpm` invocations would only be visible if one of the packages listed to be installed had further dependencies on packages NOT listed on the command line.

In such a case `rpm` will just refuse to continue, while `yum` would use any configured and enabled yum repositories to search for dependencies, and may possibly succeed.

The current working directory will NOT be searched in any case, except when it has been previously configured as an enabled `yum` repository.

Answer (score 3):

Copy all your RPMs in a directory, then install as follows:

`yum install -y --cacheonly --disablerepo=* /var/rpm_dir/*.rpm`

For specific packages you can use `yumdownloader`, example in this other thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66927190/5078874

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this and what worked for me was to run `yum localinstall enterPkgNameHere.rpm` from inside the directory where the .rpm  file is located.

Note: replace the `enterPkgNameHere.rpm` with the name of your .rpm file.

Answer (score 1):

In the case of openSUSE Leap 15, I'm receiving similar error:

```
> sudo rpm -i opera-stable_53.0.2907.68_amd64.rpm 
[sudo] password for root: 
warning: opera-stable_53.0.2907.68_amd64.rpm: Header V4 RSA/SHA512 Signature, key ID a5c7ff72: NOKEY
error: Failed dependencies:
    at is needed by opera-stable-53.0.2907.68-0.x86_64
```

I run this command to figure out what are the dependencies:

```
> sudo zypper install opera-stable_53.0.2907.68_amd64.rpm 
Loading repository data...
Reading installed packages...
Resolving package dependencies...

The following 4 NEW packages are going to be installed:
  at libfl2 libHX28 opera-stable

4 new packages to install.
Overall download size: 50.3 MiB. Already cached: 0 B. After the operation, additional 176.9 MiB will be used.
Continue? [y/n/...? shows all options] (y): n
```

Then I run this command to install dependencies:

```
> sudo zypper in at
Loading repository data...
Reading installed packages...
Resolving package dependencies...

The following 3 NEW packages are going to be installed:
  at libfl2 libHX28

3 new packages to install.
Overall download size: 208.6 KiB. Already cached: 0 B. After the operation, additional 600.4 KiB will be used.
Continue? [y/n/...? shows all options] (y): y
```

Then I run this to install the `rpm` file:

```
> sudo rpm -i opera-stable_53.0.2907.68_amd64.rpm
```

I'm **not** sure if it is the best practice, however it solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Step1: copy all the rpm pkg in given locations

Step2: if createrepo is not already installed, as it will not be by default, install it.

```
[root@pavangildamysql1 8.0.11_rhel7]# yum install createrepo
```

Step3: create repository metedata and give below permission

```
[root@pavangildamysql1 8.0.11_rhel7]# chown -R root.root /scratch/PVN/8.0.11_rhel7
[root@pavangildamysql1 8.0.11_rhel7]# createrepo /scratch/PVN/8.0.11_rhel7
Spawning worker 0 with 3 pkgs
Spawning worker 1 with 3 pkgs
Spawning worker 2 with 3 pkgs
Spawning worker 3 with 2 pkgs
Workers Finished
Saving Primary metadata
Saving file lists metadata
Saving other metadata
Generating sqlite DBs
Sqlite DBs complete
[root@pavangildamysql1 8.0.11_rhel7]# chmod -R o-w+r /scratch/PVN/8.0.11_rhel7
```

Step4: Create repository file with following contents at /etc/yum.repos.d/mysql.repo

```
[local]
name=My Awesome Repo
baseurl=file:///scratch/PVN/8.0.11_rhel7
enabled=1
gpgcheck=0
```

Step5 Run this command to install

```
[root@pavangildamysql1 local]# yum --nogpgcheck localinstall mysql-commercial-server-8.0.11-1.1.el7.x86_64.rpm
```

Answer (score -2):

Simple just run the following command.

```
sudo dnf install *package.rpm
```

Enter your password and you are done.

Answer (score -5):

Process of generating RPM from source file: 
1) download source file with.gz extention. 
2) install rpm-build and rpmdevtools from yum install. (rpmbuild folder will be generated...SPECS,SOURCES,RPMS.. folders will should be generated inside the rpmbuild folder).
3) copy the source code.gz to SOURCES folder.(rpmbuild/SOURCES)
4)Untar the tar ball by using the following command. 
go to SOURCES folder :rpmbuild/SOURCES where tar file is present. 
command: e.g tar -xvzf httpd-2.22.tar.gz
httpd-2.22 folder will be generated in the same path. Check if apr and apr-util and there in httpd-2.22/srclib folder. If apr and apr-util doesnt exist download latest version from apache site ,untar it and put it inside httpd-2.22/srclib folder. Also make sure you have pcre install in your system .

5)go to extracted folder and then type below command:
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/apache2 --with-included-apr --enable-proxy --enable-proxy-balancer --with-mpm=worker --enable-mods-static=all
6)run below command once the configure is successful:
make 
7)after successfull execution od make command run: 
checkinstall 
in tha same folder. (if you dont have checkinstall software please download latest version from site)
Also checkinstall software has bug which can be solved by following way:::::
locate checkinstallrc and then replace TRANSLATE = 1 to TRANSLATE=0 using vim command.
Also check for exclude package: EXCLUDE="/selinux"
8)checkinstall will ask for option (type R if you want tp build rpm for source file)
9)Done .rpm file will be built in RPMS folder inside rpmbuild/RPMS file...
ALL the BEST ....

Regards,
Prerana

Comment: Where did anyone ask about building anything?  This was about resolving dependencies of an already built RPM.