# How to install the libnetfilter?

Tags: linux, centos, rpm, libnet

I ran the following command

```
 sudo rpm -Uvh http://rules.emergingthreatspro.com/projects/emergingrepo/x86_64/libnetfilter_queue-devel-0.0.15-1.x86_64.rpm
```

Then i got the following result

```
Retrieving http://rules.emergingthreatspro.com/projects/emergingrepo/x86_64/libnetfilter_queue-devel-0.0.15-1.x86_64.rpm
error: Failed dependencies:
        libnetfilter_queue = 0.0.15-1 is needed by libnetfilter_queue-devel-0.0.15-1.x86_64
        libnetfilter_queue.so.1()(64bit) is needed by libnetfilter_queue-devel-0.0.15-1.x86_64
        libnetfilter_queue_libipq.so.1()(64bit) is needed by libnetfilter_queue-devel-0.0.15-1.x86_64
```

i searched for the libnetfilter_queue rpm and when i try to run the rpm i got error then also

```
rpm -Uvh libnetfilter_queue-1.0.0-2.fc15.x86_64.rpm
warning: libnetfilter_queue-1.0.0-2.fc15.x86_64.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA256 signature: NOKEY, key ID 069c8460
error: Failed dependencies:
        libnfnetlink.so.0()(64bit) is needed by libnetfilter_queue-1.0.0-2.fc15.x86_64
        rpmlib(FileDigests) <= 4.6.0-1 is needed by libnetfilter_queue-1.0.0-2.fc15.x86_64
        rpmlib(PayloadIsXz) <= 5.2-1 is needed by libnetfilter_queue-1.0.0-2.fc15.x86_64
```

My machine is i mean result of `uname -a` on my machine is

```
 2.6.18-308.el5xen #1 SMP Tue Feb 21 20:47:10 EST 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Please help me to install the libnetfilter.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you please use the following?
sudo rpm -iUvh  http://rules.emergingthreatspro.com/projects/emergingrepo/x86_64/libnetfilter_queue-devel-0.0.15-1.x86_64.rpm

Comment: You need to install the dependencies too. Frist, try to install the dependencies, the -devel package. It's best if you can use yum, if not. Perhaps, this post can help you - http://stackoverflow.com/a/13877738/2231815

Answer (score -1):

To install any package from rpm you should download/install all dependencies manually. so download

> libnfnetlink.so.0()(64bit)
>
> rpmlib(FileDigests)
>
> rpmlib(PayloadIsXz)

Or yum is a better option to install any packages, that install all dependendicies automatically.