# Install Gluon Scene Builder on RedHat 7

Tags: centos, redhat, scenebuilder

When attempting to install Gluon Scene Builder (JavaFX Scene Builder) on RedHat Workstation 7, and CentOS 7, I get a large number of unresolved dependencies, most of which seem to be standard files that should already be installed.  Any suggestions what is wrong:

```
[ron@destiny-centos Downloads]$ sudo rpm -i scenebuilder-8.2.0-1.x86_64.rpm   
[sudo] password for ron:   
error: Failed dependencies:  
    ld-linux.so.2 is needed by scenebuilder-8.2.0-1.x86_64  
    libX11.so.6 is needed by scenebuilder-8.2.0-1.x86_64  
    libXext.so.6 is needed by scenebuilder-8.2.0-1.x86_64  
    libXi.so.6 is needed by scenebuilder-8.2.0-1.x86_64 
    libXrender.so.1 is needed by scenebuilder-8.2.0-1.x86_64  
    libXtst.so.6 is needed by scenebuilder-8.2.0-1.x86_64  
    libasound.so.2 is needed by scenebuilder-8.2.0-1.x86_64  
    libc.so.6 is needed by scenebuilder-8.2.0-1.x86_64  
    libdl.so.2 is needed by scenebuilder-8.2.0-1.x86_64  
    libgcc_s.so.1 is needed by scenebuilder-8.2.0-1.x86_64  
    libm.so.6 is needed by scenebuilder-8.2.0-1.x86_64  
    libpthread.so.0 is needed by scenebuilder-8.2.0-1.x86_64  
    libthread_db.so.1 is needed by scenebuilder-8.2.0-1.x86_64
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try

```
yum --nogpgcheck localinstall scenebuilder-8.2.0-1.x86_64.rpm
```

This will install all dependencies if already available in YUM system repositories. If not, follow the instuctions on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13877738/577159).